# Rails 3.1 does not precompile images that are not referenced by CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am getting the following error:

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Photos#edit

Showing .../app/views/photos/_form.html.haml where line #49 raised:

taxonomy/focus-building.jpg isn't precompiled

Extracted source (around line #49):

46:                             = focus.code
47:                         .tooltip
48:                             %span.name= focus.name
49:                             = image_tag("taxonomy/focus-#{focus.code.downcase.dehumanize}.jpg")
50:                 / Help Overlay
51:                 .help
52:                     %a.overlay{:href=>"#", :rel=>'#help-focus'} Learn more about focus
```

This image file is located in `app/assets/images/taxonomy/focus-building.jpg`. I have run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, but as far as I can tell the images are not being copied to the `public/assets` directory.

Strangely, all assets that are referred to in SCSS using `image-url()` work fine. Why does this image report not being precompiled when referred to with `image_tag`?

Comment: Are you on Rails 3.1.1 or 3.1.0?

Comment: I'm adding a +1 on this. I'm on Rails 3.1.3 and I'm having the same issue. I'm about ready to punch the asset pipeline in the face.

Comment: @Andrew: did you get this to work finally? I am getting the same issue with the assets served by image_tag not working in production!

Comment: @bpn To be honest I finally moved the images that I needed to refer to outside of CSS to the public folder. I haven't gone back and tried a different fix, there may be a better way or the problem may have gone away with updates to Rails... I haven't tested it so I don't know.

Comment: @Andrew- I came to know what the issue was in my case..the images were working all the time! I just had to empty the cache of my browser and reload the pages! It must be something to do with the expiry headers.. But all's well now..

Answer (score 2):

If you have the assets.digest option enabled this will add a hash at the end of the name and so a static reference to that file will no longer work, change any statically-referenced assets so that they use the helper methods.

Comment: For what it's worth, this did seem to help me. Somehow, enabling digests in production mode ended up making the server serve up the assets more reliably. I still want to punch the asset pipeline in the face, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with image_tag. I got the problem solved by using live compilation.

In production.rb

- config.assets.compile = true

Comment: Right well, that would work except that my deployment environment cannot do live compilation for the time being. So unfortunately this isn't an option.

Comment: It's a workaround, and thus works in a pinch — but it still shouldn't really be turned on in production if you're concerned about performance (and let's face it — in production, *you're worried about performance*).